# How to use extent reports for individual steps

Tags: extentreports, selenium-extent-report

How can we use extent report logs for individual steps. My main test is as follows

```html
@Test(testName = "Validate SinglePage and Multiple Page", enabled = true, priority = 1, groups = {"Section Formatting"})
 public void SingleSection(String username, String password, String viewName, String r1, String r2, String r3, String r4, String r5, String SecItem1, String SecItem2, String DispStyle, String fType) throws InterruptedException {
  
  extentTest = extent.startTest("SingleSection");
  
  extentTest.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Login to the system");
  
  login.loginToTenant(username, password);
  
  extentTest.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Access the content menu");
  // select view from content menu button
  createContentMenuButton.setContentMenuButton();
  
  extentTest.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Select the view");
  // choose view
  reportView.selectView(viewName);
  
  extentTest.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Create the report");
  // create the report in report builder
  createChart.createReport(r1, r2, r3, r4, r5);
  
  extentTest.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Add fields to sections");
  // Adds fields to sections
  sections.dragAndDropToSections(SecItem1, SecItem2);
```

For example If I want to put steps for one of the methods ex- loginToTenant, the system throughs null value exception error.

the code for the method loginToTenant is as follows

```html
public class loginPage extends ConfigReader {
 WebDriver driver;
  public ExtentReports extent;
 public ExtentTest extentTest;
 

 public loginPage(WebDriver driver) {
  
  this.driver = driver;

 }

 // locators for login page
 By userName = By.name("email");
 By password = By.name("password");
 By submitButton = By.id("logonButton");
 By licenseWarning = By.partialLinkText("Click Here To Continue");
 By plusButton = By.className("create-menu-container");
 By banner = By.className("i4sidenav_width");
 By logout = By.id("logoffBtn");

 /**
  * perform login to yellowfin and verify successful login
  * 
  * @param uName
  * @param passwd
  * @return
  */
 public String loginToTenant(String uName, String passwd) {

  String loginmsg = null;
  long d = 1000;
  try {
      
      extentTest.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Login to the system"); //I am getting an error on this line with null pointer exception
   driver.findElement(userName).clear();
   driver.findElement(userName).sendKeys(uName);
   driver.findElement(password).clear();
      driver.findElement(password).sendKeys(passwd);
   driver.findElement(submitButton).click();
```

Comment: You've basically got two options: Either add the logging steps manually to the report, or utilize a BDD tool such as Cucumber or JBehave and use the BDD options in ExtentReports to map the steps to the reports, which is easier if using Cucumber, but I've implemented my own class in JBehave to accomplish more or less the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How do I add the steps manually ? Please advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wants to create individual steps for loginToTenant method, you can create extentReport in loginPage class similarly. And it will create individual steps for it.